# Date objects in dictionaries change timezone in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, dictionary, timestamp

To avoid day light saving issues with date objects, I use `UTC`. For example:

`new Date(2019,8,20, 9, 0)` gives `2019-09-20T08:00:00.000Z`

`new Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,20, 9, 0))` gives `2019-09-20T09:00:00.000Z` -- what I want

My issue now is that when I add that date to a dictionary, It uses local timezone somehow. For example:

```
const b = {}

b[Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,20, 9, 0))] = true
```

gives the following:

```
{ 'Fri Sep 20 2019 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)': true }
```

Comment: new Date(2019,8,20, 9, 0).toISOString() try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following to get the UTC time -

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,20,9,0)).toUTCString()
b[utcDate] = true
```

**EDIT**
You should use `ISOString()` format to get format like `2019-09-20T09:00:00.000Z`

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,20,9,0)).toISOString()
b[utcDate] = true
```

Comment: I would like to save it in the same format e.g ```2019-09-20T09:00:00.000Z```

Comment: @AbdulazizIsmail I have edited my answer. I thought you just wanted to get rid of local timezone problem.

Comment: That works thank you! Why does the format change when setting the object key to the date object? Is this default dictionary behavior in Javascript?

Comment: `new Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,20, 9, 0))` - this is a date instance of UTC timezone. But `b[Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,20, 9, 0))] = true` - this would give you date string. And as you didn't define which type of date string you want, so by default it gets converted into local timezone formatted date string.